# Is there a setup_class/teardown_class for Rails tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

I need to have a setup and teardown method for some Rails tests that is class or system wide, yet I have only found a way to define a regular setup/teardown that works on a per test level.

For example:

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  setup do
    puts "Setting up"
  end

  teardown do
    puts "tearing down"
  end
end
```

will execute the outputs for each test case, but I would like something like:

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  setup_fixture do
    puts "Setting up"
  end

  teardown_fixture do
    puts "tearing down"
  end
end
```

which would execute the setup`_`fixture **before** all test methods, and then execute teardown`_`fixture **after** all test methods.

Is there any such mechanism?  If not, is there an easy way to monkey patch this mechanism in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several popular test frameworks that build on `Test::Unit` and provide this behavior:

**[RSpec](http://rspec.info/)**

```
describe "A Widget" do
  before(:all) do
    # stuff that gets run once at startup
  end
  before(:each) do
    # stuff that gets run before each test
  end
  after(:each) do
    # stuff that gets run after each test
  end
  after(:all) do
    # stuff that gets run once at teardown
  end
end
```

**[Test/Spec](http://test-spec.rubyforge.org/)**

```
context "A Widget" do
  # same syntax as RSpec for before(:all), before(:each), &c.
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I think rails provides such a functionality for fixtures. You can use fixtures by saying

```
  fixtures :users
```

in your test files

and besides you can also use

```
def setup
  #....
end
```

in your test files as well,